# can't seem to find std::thread in msvc++ 2010 express

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've been reading about various new additions to c++ recently that i'm really excited about and i've already been through the new std::unique_ptr and std::shared_ptr objects, which are incredibly useful, and now i'm looking for that native thread library i've heard about and can't seem to find it anywhere. I was reading and went looking for thread.h and msvc++ 2010 express doesn't seem to have it. Did the newest versions of msvc++ not come with this new thread library, or is it just the express version that doesn't come with it, or am i just being silly and have to go looking for a copy of it on the internet? I currently have to do threading via windows functions which i feel are overcomplicated when trying to use mutexes and they're also operating system specific, so i'm really excited to find this standard library implementation :\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all C++11 changes are in the Visual C++ 2010 compiler.  You will need to use boost::thread or just::thread as alternatives, or use the [Visual Studio 11 Beta](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads):

Comment: ah alrighty then, at least I've got smart pointers for now. I was gonna look at boost::thread next anyway, just wanted to make sure there wasn't an available standard library equivalent. So it's safe to assume that the next release of visual studio will most likely have std::thread available?

Answer (score 0):

None of the editions of VS2010 come with `std::thread`. Remember that VS2010 pre-dated the C++11 standard.

You could try `boost::thread` as an alternative. The design of `std::thread` is an evolution from `boost::thread` and so it should not be too traumatic to switch to `std::thread` when it becomes more widely implemented.

Comment: Sadly, `std::thread` has no interruption points. Reason enough for me to stick with `boost::thread`, as long as they don't remove it

Answer (score 0):

VS2012 Beta should be released this month, will be better than the developer preview.